# Why is $E(Z | Y) = 0$?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Let $Z$ be a random variable distributed $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. Let $Y = Z^2$.

Apparently, $E(Z \mid Y) = E(Z \mid Z^2) = 0$ due to "symmetry." Why is that?

Comment: If you are given the value of $Y = Z^2$, then you know that $Z$ can only have value $\sqrt{Y}$ or $-\sqrt{Y}$. Can you think of any reason why these two values might be equally likely? How might the answer differ if $Z \sim N(\mu, 1)$ where $\mu \neq 0$?

Comment: Ah! Is that because the normal curve is symmetric about the mean, so both $\sqrt{Y}$ and $-\sqrt{Y}$ are equally likely? I presume if the mean shifted, then we can't make conclusions since $\sqrt{Y}$ and $-\sqrt{Y}$ are no longer equally likely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$-Y$ is also $N(0,1)$ distributed and the $\sigma$ algebras generated by $-Y$ and $Y$ are the same, so $E[-Y\mid (-Y)^2]=E[Y\mid Y^2]$, which gives the wanted result.

It can be extended to integrable random variables $X$ such that $X$ has the same law as $-X$.

Answer (score 5):

For completion, note that for all mesurable $f$ such that $E(|f(Y)|) < \infty$, $$E(f(Y)\mid Z) = \frac{f(Z) + f(-Z)}{2}.$$

Here $f\colon x\mapsto x$ is odd, hence $E(Y\mid Z) = \frac{Z-Z}{2}=0$.

*Another example of interest :* if you take $f(x)=e^{i\theta x}$, you get $E(e^{i\theta Y} \mid Z) = \cos(\theta Z)$